# Securely delete file in php

Tags: php, security, delete-file

I would like to *securely* delete a file in PHP. I thought of the following options

- Use `shred`through a system call. (exec, shell_exec, ....), but in most shared hostings, those functions are disabled and are forbidden if safe mode is on.
- Open it through `fopen`and overwriting it with random data and `unlink`it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doing my research I found it was disabled on some servers.
- The best option I thought of, is using `file_put_content`to overwrite its data with zeros, and then deleting it.

Question is: **is file_put_content guaranteed to overwrite the file ?** I wrote a simplistic approach in the following example: would this code delete a file securely ? Would there be a considerable performance hit ? How do I make it more "large file friendly" ?

```
function secure_delete($file_path)
{
    $file_size = filesize($file_path);
    $new_content = str_repeat('0', $file_size);
    file_put_contents($file_path, $new_content);
    unlink($file_path);
}
```

**UPDATE**: The code I posted is more about demonstrating the overwriting of a file: the actual code would be an implementation of [DoD 5220.22-M](http://www.zdelete.com/dod.htm)

Comment: If you need to do _anything_ with files securely, don't use shared hosting.

Comment: I am aware of the security implications and cross-site compromise risk that comes with shared hosting. I would like nonetheless to know if the approach I posted is "secure"

Comment: Depends on your definition of secure. If the hosting is any good, then they will for example, keep backups. Do you count it as securely removed if it exists in a 3rd party backup?

Comment: Jon has a very good point here. Unless you can know the exact storage implementation used, you can never know if it will be "secure"

Comment: I've updated the question and removed the shared hosting, I'm aware that it's inherently insecure, but it's a detail for my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the device type (spindle vs SSD), your approach will be different.  Look **[here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/disk-wiping-and-data-forensics-separating-myth-from-science/)** for some insight. And please, dont overwrite 35 times on an SSD, unless you are aiming to render it useless as a device.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so simply. If you erase file with '0' values it can be still posible to restore. You should use any of algorihms for really secure deletion. For example: [Gutmann method](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html)

It use 35 consecutive writes per file.

Answer (score 1):

Found a PHP library that does this https://github.com/DanielRuf/secure-shred